# Buffer link with a stream in I/O

Tags: c++

I found from [C++ I/O](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp10_IO.html) that streams are merely a connection between the source (file, keyboard, network etc.) but I am still not able to understand where the buffers (which controls the flow of data) are located (on which stage) when it comes to streams. All this to understand `streambuf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffers are located at *ends* of  stream:

`ostream ------> buffer -------> file, keyboard, console`

`istream <------ buffer <------- file, key board, console`